# Magento Goal Conversion Tracking

Tags: magento-1.9, development, google-analytics, google, google-adwords

I'm trying to track member applications referred by my CPC Ads.
I've set everything up on the Adwords end to track this and they have produced a snippet to place in the header of the "thank you" page.

However I can't seem to find a way using magento 1.9 to edit the header code of a specific page, only the header code of every page such as for the overriding adwords/analytics code which I've already set up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/193138/20064

Comment: Hey,
Whenever I search for the www.mypage.com/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/header/new-header.phtml.
it brings me to "page not found" on my site....

Comment: Hey, it is a file path so you have to check this in your Magento directories, also `ultimo/default` is theme name and you may have a different theme so replace it with your theme name

Comment: if `new-header.phtml` file is not there in your directory then replicate your existing header.phtml and name the new file new-header.phtml, also add the additional content/code you want in new file.

Comment: Thanks.
Now i've finally found the directory.
Will this work for a specific CMS page as the thank you page is set up that way.(we have other CMS pages that I don't want to track)

Comment: if you want to change it for a CMS page only then you can add layout code(without handle tag) in your cms page layout column, check this - https://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-change-the-header-of-magento-cms-page/

Comment: And this will place the snippet in the <head> </Head> code of that page ?

Comment: Yes it will add that snippet to the cms page header

Comment: what is the success page for "member applications"? Do they go through the standard checkout process to buy a membership or are you trying to track successful customer registrations?